# Hibernate error: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, hibernate-mapping

I am having an issue in setting up a many to many relationship in my entities. And I don't understand why

```
failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: cardgame.bean.User.card in cardgame.bean.Card.users
```

My Entities:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String id;

public BaseEntity() {
    this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
}
```

My user emtity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

@Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String username;

@Column(name = "uuid", nullable = false)
private String uuid;

@Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String email;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Card> cards;

@Column(name = "isActive", nullable = false)
private boolean isActive;
}
```

My card entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "cards")
public class Card extends BaseEntity {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "card")
private List<User> users;

@Column(name = "strength", nullable = false)
private int strength;

@Column(name = "isActive", nullable = false)
private boolean isActive;
}
```

The users and cards tables have a many-to-many relationship via user_card table:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_card")
public class UserCard implements Serializable {

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private User user;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "card_id", nullable = false)
private Card card;

@Column(name = "cardCount", nullable = false)
private int cardCount;
}
```

What am i doing incorrect. Please help me

Comment: Card and User should have a Collection<UserCard>, nt a Collection<Card> or a Collection<User>.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you, you are the best, i was just inattentive